# Leer ultima linea entrada al Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Esta la entrada de datos. El problema es que no me reconoce la última línea. Una vez le doy *ENTER*, sí me salta a la siguiente linea y me muestra el último resultado, pero debería hacérmelo automáticamente. Me mostrará 1 si el resultado es válido y 0 si el resultado no es válido. Eso me lo hace bien y el `Scanner` me lee bien la entrada. Pero lo que necesito es que me lo haga automáticamente todas las lineas. He estado buscando y con un `.nextLine()` debería de ir, y es el que ya he usado.

```
5
6011 5940 0319 9511
5537 0213 6797 6815
5574 8363 8022 9735
3044 8507 9391 30
6370 1675 9034 6211 774
```

Mi código es este:

```
package Targeta;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Targeta{

    //Funcion booleana que comprueba la longitud del array, como pide el enunciado, entre 12 y 19.
    public static boolean Comprobacion (int[] arrayNumeros){
        return arrayNumeros.length>=12 && arrayNumeros.length<=19;
    }

    //Funcion que separa por caracteres, un numero =>10 y devuelve la suma de sus zifras; por ejemplo(12), 1 y 2, devuelve 3.
    public static int Suma(int numero){
        String zifra1;
        zifra1=Integer.toString(numero);
        char a=zifra1.charAt(0);
        char b=zifra1.charAt(1);
        int c=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(a));
        int d=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(b));
        numero=c+d;
        return numero;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Variables
        int repeticiones;
        String targeta;
        int suma = 0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Entramos los datos que necesitamos
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero de casos que quieres probar y cada numero de targeta.");
        repeticiones = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();

        //Bucle que se repite tantas veces como el numero de casos que hayamos entrado.

        while (repeticiones != 0) {

            targeta = teclado.nextLine();

            //Pasamos cada valor de la targeta introducida a un array y eliminamos los espacios introducidos en el Scanner.
            targeta = targeta.replaceAll("[' ']", "");

            int[] arrayTargeta = new int[targeta.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTargeta.length; i++) {
                arrayTargeta[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(targeta.charAt(i)));
            }

            //Revisamos la longitud del array.
            if (Targeta.Comprobacion(arrayTargeta)) {

                //Realizaremos operaciones de forma descendiente, por eso empezamos con el valor del array lenght, y cada dos posiciones.
                for (int i = arrayTargeta.length - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
                    arrayTargeta[i] = arrayTargeta[i] * 2;
                    if (arrayTargeta[i] >= 10) {
                        arrayTargeta[i] = Targeta.Suma(arrayTargeta[i]);
                    }
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < arrayTargeta.length; i++) {
                    suma = suma + arrayTargeta[i];
                }
                suma = suma % 10;

                if (suma == 0) {
                    System.out.println("1");//Si el modul del valor suma/10 dona 0, ens mostrara per pantalla 1;OK.
                } else {
                    System.out.println("0");//Si el modul del valor suma/10 no és, ens mostrara per pantalla 0;NO OK.
                }
                suma = 0;//Reiniciem el valor de suma
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("0");
            }
            repeticiones --;
        }
        teclado.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: no me queda claro: dada la entrada, ¿Qué salida tiene que dar tu programa?

Comment: La salida tiene que ser 0 o 1, eso ya funciona, el problema lo tengo con la lectura de la ultima linea en el Scanner.

Comment: ¿Y dices que te pasa cuando copias y pegas todo?

Comment: exacto, tengo que copiar y pegar en consola la entrada que he dejado arriba directamente.

Comment: No veo nada raro en tu código, lo he copiado y pegado y suelta 5 números, que son o bien 0 o 1

Comment: Pero el ultimo numero te lo suelta automáticamente, o le tienes que dar a ENTER? Lo que necesito es que me suelte el ultimo numero automáticamente.

Comment: Hay que darle a enter porque en tu entrada no estás poniendo el último enter. Las cuatro primeras líneas tienen un salto de línea pero la última no, y nextLine requiere un salto de línea para empezar a capturar texto.

Comment: Y como puedo añadirlo? Es lo que no consigo.

Comment: He recuperado la pregunta. Alguien se ha tomado la molestia y el tiempo de intentar ayudarte, si no tienes una razón de peso no deberías eliminar la pregunta.

Comment: Perdona por eso, era una actividad para clase y me ha surgido esa duda, y he borrado la pregunta por si mis compañeros entraban no vieran todo mi codigo hecho, luego me he olvidado de recuperar la pregunta al acabar la clase. Y muchas gracias David por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema no está en el programa, está en la entrada. `Scanner.nextLine()` tokeniza la entrada que le das y busca hasta el siguiente salto de línea, pero tu entrada no lo tiene. Para `Scanner`, tu entrada tiene un aspecto así:

```
5\n                       // Obviemos que tienes que limpiarlo aquí
6011 5940 0319 9511\n
5537 0213 6797 6815\n
5574 8363 8022 9735\n
3044 8507 9391 30\n
6370 1675 9034 6211 774   // Aquí falta el token de final de línea
```

Para arreglarlo, no hay nada más que añadir un salto de línea a la última línea. Cambiando tu entrada de esto:

```
5                       
6011 5940 0319 9511
5537 0213 6797 6815
5574 8363 8022 9735
3044 8507 9391 30
6370 1675 9034 6211 774
```

A esto (**Ojo al salto de línea al final**):

```
5                       
6011 5940 0319 9511
5537 0213 6797 6815
5574 8363 8022 9735
3044 8507 9391 30
6370 1675 9034 6211 774
```

Debería bastar.